# How do I change the location where dependency properties appear in the WPF designer properties window?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dependency-properties

I have a few dependency properties that I would like to customize when interpreted by the WPF designer.

**How can I set which section each `DependencyProperty` will appear inside of the Properties Window in Visual Studio?**

Is this even an acceptable practice?  I expected to be able to do this through specifying attributes, but I'm not finding any documentation on it.

I want to choose the **Common** section for most of my properties, but I also want to specify the **Brushes** section as well.  See image below.

[image]

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: By the way, they appear in the **Other** section by default.  I'd like to move then out of there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx):

```
[Category("Common")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```